# "Das, ob ..., weiß ich nicht"

Tags: pronoun, subordinate-clause

Angenommen, man wird gefragt, ob der Bus schon losgefahren ist. Wenn man darauf nicht antworten kann, dann kann man sagen: *Ob der Bus schon losgefahren ist, weiß ich nicht.* Man könnte auch sagen: *Das weiß ich nicht.*

Kann man auf die Frage *Ist der Bus schon losgefahren?* auch das Folgende sagen?

> Das, ob der Bus schon losgefahren ist, weiß ich nicht.

Answer (score 6):

Sagen kann man es schon, es wird nur der Funktion des Pronomens nicht gerecht. Das [anaphorische Pronomen](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gruwi.ansicht?v_typ=o&v_id=3749) dient ja gerade dazu, auf ein vorhergehendes Nomen oder einen vorhergehenden Satz Bezug zu nehmen. Damit kann man sich die Wiederholung des Bezugsobjektes (in diesem Fall der „ob“-Satz) sparen.

Sinnvoll kann es vielleich dann sein, wenn das Bezugsobjekt klarstellungsbedürftig ist, und/oder wenn man es nur partiell aufnehmen möchte:

> „*Wissen Sie, ob der letzte Bus, der von hier zum Martplatz fährt, schon losgefahren ist?“* — *„Das – ob der Bus schon losgefahren ist – weiss ich leider nicht. Zum Marktplatz können Sie aber auch die Tramlinie 4 nehmen.“*

Je nach Sprechsituation - etwa wenn die Frage in einem längerem Satzgefüge formuliert war - ist die anaphorische Verbindung zu schwach, um sofort einleuchtend zu sein. Dann könnte man die Frage in einer Parenthese wiederholen, sie also in den Antwortsatz einfügen. Eine solche Parenthese würde ich aber eher per Gedankenstrich kenntlich machen anstatt durch Kommata. Wenn ich ein Komma sehe, erwarte ich eher einen Nebensatz und keinen selbständigen Einschub.

Eleganter ist es aber auf jeden Fall, auf das „das“ zu verzichten, denn letztlich ist es schlicht überflüssig.

Answer (score 0):

Klingt für mich merkwürdig, ich würde sagen, das geht nicht. Eher würde ich sagen: Das weiß ich nicht, also, ob der Bus schon losgefahren ist.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Es gibt eine [tour] der Seite. Fragen darüber, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [Help].

Comment: Antworten, in denen der Autor bekannt gibt, es selbst nicht so genau zu wissen, sind nicht sehr hilfreich. Hilfreich sind klare fundierte Antworten, die auch eine nachvollziehbare Begründung enthalten.